# Update facebook status with C#

Tags: c#, facebook, status

My desktop application should update my facebook status.
Is there an API that allows to update the status with a login and pwd ?

Thanks in advance for your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure there is!

[.Net FacebookToolKit](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookToolkit) it was done by a 3rd party for Microsoft, and then published as open source on CodePlex.

There is proper documentation and even videos on how to do your first desktop application and how to publish stories, status, etc.
[FaceBookToolKit CodePlex documentation](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=35534)

Comment: Found this link http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode22CAndVBNETLibrariesToDiggFlickrFacebookYouTubeTwitterLiveServicesGoogleAndOtherWeb20APIs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[There is the Status.set API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/status.set/) that allows you to do this kind of thing.

Comment: You need to make an FB application do set your status.

Comment: Weird its nor working for me in my work computer or down for everyone, so I just logged in to my home computer, doesnt work there either

Comment: and... now its working both at work and home and down for everyone... thats weird.. maybe it was down temporarily?

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook Send User Status](http://vatlab.com/asp-net-facebook-controls/send-user-status)