# Update facebook page's status using C#

Tags: c#, facebook, status

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update facebook status with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058210/update-facebook-status-with-c)

Does anybody know how to to update facebook page's status programatically using C#?
I do not want to prompt user for logging to facebook as I have their username and password. So all should have to be done behind the scene.

Comment: There's no Facebook-supported way to log in via username and password to make a post - you'll have to get the user to log in and install your app.